# Facebook app on localhost on windows server 2012

Tags: facebook, ssl-certificate

I have a Facebook app which is defined in Facebook as localhost.
I have it installed on a windows server 2012 with a self signed certificate issues to that server name.

In the IE (and chrome), if I open https://localhost it doesn't go through the Facebook and fails on certificate, if I open https://servername it goes through the Facebook but again, doesn't open claiming it doesn't have a valid security certificate.

I created 2 certificates, one for localhost (issues by "localhost") and one for the servername, both don't work.

I tried everything I could find online and some advice from friends including changing security settings on IE.

Any ideas will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking; what is “it doesn't go through the Facebook” supposed to mean? // When using a self-signed certificate, you need to get your browser to accept it once – add an exception or even import the certificate, so that on subsequent visits to that URL it will accept it without errors and without asking again. You should do that by calling the URL directly first, not inside the FB iframe already – because in the latter situation, not all browsers will offer to ignore the warning and accept the certificate, some might just not display anything at all inside the iframe.

Comment: When I say "go through Facebook" I mean that I get the top and the right panels of Facebook (the blue bar with the name, "Home"... and the suggested apps.
The certificate is imported and I see it in the list when binding the site to https in the IIS.
when I connect directly, if I use the certificate for the server name it says  that it was issues to a different website, if I use the certificate for localhost it says that the certificate was not issues by a trusted certificate authority

Comment: You have to make your test browser accept this invalid certificate, so that it will accept it without warnings/errors, and without asking again in the future.

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: Depends on your browser. How about a little _reseach_? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate